# Extracting content from within meta itemprop using R

Tags: regex, xml, r, xpath, sapply

I am attempting to extract the text from within the content section of the following.

```
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-02-24T11:34:57Z"/>
<meta itemprop="description" content="South Africa's gross domestic output 
(GDP) expanded by a much stronger 4.1 percent in the fourth quarter"/>
```

I'm particularly interested in extracting the time and date from "datePublished" and "description".  Now the interesting thing is that I can extract the "description" text, using

```
xpathSApply(story2, "//head/meta[@name=\"description\"]/@content")
```

but not `datePublished` even though I am using identical syntax which produces only a `NULL` result.

I'm at a loss to explain this and wondered if anyone knows why `xpathSApply` does not extract the `datePublished` when it extracts the description, and what the correct format is. I can't extract it using substring operations via grep either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the code that you are trying, cause I believe it should be:

```
'<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-02-24T11:34:57Z"/>
<meta itemprop="description" content="South Africa\'s gross domestic output (GDP) expanded by a much stronger 4.1 percent in the fourth quarter"/>' -> foo
library(XML)
bar <- xmlParse(foo)
datePublished <- xpathSApply(bar, "//meta[@itemprop='datePublished']/@content")
description <- xpathSApply(bar, "//meta[@itemprop='description']/@content")
```